# Select Statement depending on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to select a particular set of records depending on Primary Key. Suppose my Primary Key is integer which are not sequential. If I specify 1023(which exists in table) then I should get the next specified number(suppose 50) records.

Can this be possible to do it?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you searched on here for a solution? Search for "sql paging" perhaps.

Comment: Do you want to get the records ordered by the primary key, some other key or "unordered"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select top 50 *
from MyTable
where MyKey > 1023
order by MyKey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from [Table Name]
where primaryKey >= 1023
and primaryKey < (1023 + 50)
```

Comment: This solution would work in a situation that involves sequential key values, which the OP stated is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to calculate the result set. For the simple example where you want to find the result + 50, you can do something like this:

```
select primaryKey+50
from [TableName]
where primaryKey=1023
```

If I've misunderstood your question, please let me know